# Reshaping groupby data into a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create a dataframe that takes the 1st index and makes it into a column.

My grouping code:
`candy_df.groupby(['BAG', 'LOLLIPOP']).agg('count')['STICKID']`

Right now my grouping returns this:

```
BAG      LOLLIPOP
011111     CHOCO          69
           VANILL         33
011112     CHOCO         133
           VANILL        129
```

I'd like to take the 1st index, `LOLLIPOP`, and make the different flavors be the columns:

```
BAG        CHOCO         VANILL
011111     69             33
011112     133            129
```

Comment: `df.unstack('LOLLIPOP')`?

Comment: Thanks, the column names are now STICKID/CHOCO and STICKID/VANILL. How do I "unlayer" the column names so it's just CHOCO and VANILL?

Comment: `candy_df.groupby(['BAG', 'LOLLIPOP'])['STICKID'].count()`

Comment: Also read `pivot_table` with `aggfunc='count'` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-to-pivot-a-dataframe).

Answer (score 0):

`candy_df.groupby(['BAG', 'LOLLIPOP'])['STICKID'].count().unstack()`

This question was also answered under Question 4 under [How to pivot a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-to-pivot-a-dataframe)